# Log4j2 Different color per logger

Tags: java, log4j2

In my project I use Log4j 2.17.1.
I would like to format the output so that the class names have different colors.

```java
public class MyClass {
    Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(MyClass.class.getSimpleName());
    
    //...

    LOGGER.debug("Some Information");
}
public class MySecondClass {
    Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(MySecondClass.class.getSimpleName());

    //...
    
    LOGGER.debug("Another Output");
}
```

[image]

In my example, I want the two classes to appear in different (perhaps random) colors (instead of yellow as in the example).

My current pattern layout:

```
%highlight{${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}}{FATAL=red blink, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow bold, INFO=green, DEBUG=green bold, TRACE=blue} : %style{%logger{36}:}{blue} %msg%n
```

Is this possible with Log4j?

Comment: It seems random colors per logger aren't supported in log4j. The best option for me is to keep logs plain and give the coloring job to the external viewing tool

Comment: But you also can try to play with custom Layout implementation - extend the original one which does all the highlighting and wrap it with your specific logic which will understand random colors per logger

Comment: in the second option, you should take care of color persistence - when you restart application or look at logs from two separate instances - colors should be consistent

Answer (score 0):

Per defeault log4j writes simple text files with no fancy formatting applied (FileAppender, ConsoleAppender).

I have never done this, but I believe you can add [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) using a suitable formatting pattern, then enjoy the colours when the log output is sent to a terminal capable of understanding these sequences.

Comment: he uses log4j highlighting feature, which adds all the necessary escape sequences